# Menubar and Finder icons missing

Tags: macos, finder, menu-bar

Since about 5 days ago all system icons in the Finder sidebar (folders, disks), the Finder Menubar (view options, buttons, back and forward) and in the display menu bar (spotlight, wifi, bluetooth) have disappeared:

[image]
[image]

When I log in as a different user or as a guest, the problem does not present itself. Also note that it's not just system icons, Alfred.app and Flux.app are missing from the menu bar too.

I've reset the pram, started in save mode but nothing seems to fix it. 
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: any luck? I have exactly the same problem!

Comment: No joy, I ended up reinstalling my entire system.

Answer (score 1):

Two options I can think of:

1) Clear the Finder's icon cache, from Terminal, & reboot
`sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;`

2) Or run the latest combo updater (rather than the delta), from https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, tried both but they didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Then it's likely to be some 3rd party app you have running on the one account, but not the others. You've a whole lot of stuff I don't recognise on your menu bar

Answer (score 1):

I restarted my laptop into safeboot by holding the shift key. Then I logged in while holding the shift key. After a restart the icons were back.

The whole procedure is described here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6738097?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.